# How to keep a date current in Markdown files

Tags: date, markdown

I'd like to put a copyright in a LICENSE.md file, but I'd hate to go back on Jan 1st every year to update the date, is there a way to do:

`Copyright [current year] Name` in Markdown?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no support for this in vanilla [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), but there are several versions of Markdown floating around out there.

If you update your question to specify a Markdown processor we may be able to provide a more specific answer.

Comment: do github have something for this?

Comment: @MarlonLópez, GitHub's Markdown rendering (e.g. for READMEs) does not. GitHub [_Pages_](https://pages.github.com/) can be generated using something like [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/), which likely _can_.