# Is there markdown syntax that will allow my copyright date to automatically update each year?

Tags: markdown

I am adding a copyright page to a markdown file and I want it to automatically update each year so I don't have to manually update the file each year. I am using 'vanilla' markdown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep a date current in Markdown files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094661/how-to-keep-a-date-current-in-markdown-files)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything dynamic with Markdown.

However, something that is used a lot in the industry, is integrating images or SVGs that are served dynamically. Here's an example: if you look at [the beginning of React Native's readme](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/README.md#react-native------), you'll see some badges:

[image: Circle CI Status]

The markdown under these badges is the following:

```
![Circle CI Status](https://circleci.com/gh/facebook/react-native.svg?style=shield)
^ image
  ^ image description
                    ^ image link
```

Actually, `circleci.com` did some work in the background to dynamically serve an image corresponding to the React Native repository.

One can imagine something similar for updating the copyright every year in your case. Set up a server that serves an image or svg that displays `© <current-year>`, and have the following markdown:

```
![copyright](https://your-server.com/copyright)
```